# What effect does React.cloneElement() have on React's reconciliation of the virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have inherited a code base that makes frequent use of `React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {})` in the `render()` method of container components.  Like this:

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {})}
    </div>
  }
}


...


import {Route} from 'react-router'
import App from '..';
import SomePureComponent from '..';
<Route
  component={App}
  path='/'
>
  <Route
    component={SomePureComponent}
    path='/test'
  />
</Route>
```

Isn't this an anti-pattern?  It was my understanding that calling functions like `React.cloneElement()` will return a new instance on each render, alerting the virtual DOM of new changes it must reconcile, and thus leaving `PureComponent` ineffective at minimizing re-renders.  Am I misunderstanding something about Virtual DOM reconciliation?

Comment: I'm not certain enough to answer definitively, but IMO using `React.cloneElement` without adding or modifying props seems like it would be utterly pointless.

Comment: I think reconciliation happens *after* you return new "Elements" back from `render()`, therefore using `cloneElement` is not bad for performance (not an expert either)